# Treeview not working with sitemap

Tags: asp.net

i've created a sitemap with my default.aspx page, coded it accordingly, then added a sitemapdatasource control as well as a treeview control to the page. I then altered out the code for the treeview by adding 'datasourceID' for it to link to the sitemapdatasource. i still however get an error when viewing the page in a browser, not knowing what else to do. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#DFDFFF" Font-Names="Arial" 
            Font-Size="Medium" Height="557px" Width="913px">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="223px" BackColor="#3333CC" 
                ForeColor="White" 
                style="top: 58px; left: 10px; position: absolute; height: 437px; margin-top: 70px; text-align: center;">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="#003399" ForeColor="White" 
                    style="margin-left: 259px; top: -109px; left: -258px; position: absolute; width: 906px; height: 105px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
                        style="z-index: 1; left: 293px; top: 33px; position: absolute; width: 345px; text-align: center;" 
                        Text="Web Page Header"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                    style="z-index: 1; left: 56px; top: 7px; position: absolute; width: 99px" 
                    Text="Menu"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />

                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
                <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
                </asp:TreeView>

            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="this is the home page">
        <siteMapNode url="Aboutus.aspx" title="About us"  description="this is the contact page" />
        <siteMapNode url="Contactus.aspx" title="Contact Us"  description="this is the whatever page" />
        <siteMapNode url="History.aspx" title="Our History"  description="this is the whatever page" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist. 
this is the error i get when requesting the page.

Comment: Not sure, but I'd comment out the outer two before trying anything else.

Comment: It's probably your URL entries; check my one with root operator in my answer

Comment: its an exercise provided by my lecturer which requires this additional navigation. It doesn't have a web.config file at all. I think it may be this, because it's giving the following exception:Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist.

Comment: You need a Web.Config or your page won't even render.

Comment: haha thanks! im gonna kill em!. Thanks a bunch for your help cheftain! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see several probs, so easy way is to give you a sample of a working one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home" title="Home" description="Home">
        <siteMapNode url="~/About" title="About" description="About">
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

In your ASPX page:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"  
    HoverNodeStyle-Height="0" ImageSet="BulletedList">
</asp:TreeView>

<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

Also, you need to lose the inline CSS ;-)